# Counting the grouped elements of a Dataframe in Python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that I am trying to group by and sum.  I was able to achieve this, but I'd also like to count the grouped by elements.

```
sessions_summed = df.groupby("screens_completed").sum()
print sessions_summed
```

using this, I get this output:

```
screens_completed     sessions         
0                         6
1                         1
2                         3
3                         1
4                         1
5                         1
9                        33
12                        8
13                      872
14                   103292
```

What I would like is to see the count of how many times each entity in screens completed (i.e. how many times did 14 appear) appeared alongside this new summed sessions column.  And then I would like divide the summed column by the count column.

How would I do this?

Comment: Do you mean, you're trying to compute the mean number of sessions corresponding to each screens_completed group?

Comment: yes, but I would like to see the counts separately in their own column as well

Comment: Can you link an example input csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to count the number of times a certain value appears in a column.

You can take advantage of the `aggfunc` argument in the `pivot_table` function.

```
sessions_summed = df.groupby("screens_completed").sum()

#the below line will count the number of times each value occurs in screens_completed.
sessions_summed["count"] = df.pivot_table(index="screens_completed", values="sessions", aggfunc=len)
sessions_summed["mean"] = sessions_summed["sessions"] / sessions_summed["count"]
```

#### So what's going on here?

`pivot_table` will group your rows based on the column you specify with the `index` parameter. For each of the columns you pass the 'values' parameter, `pivot_table` will try to compute some summarizing information to put in that column using all of the values in rows corresponding to rows with a matching index value. The `aggfunc` parameter allows you to tell `.pivot_table` how you want that column summarized.

For example, let's say you have the following table:

```
index   screens_completed     sessions         
0       0                     2
1       1                     4
2       1                     1
3       1                     3
3       0                     3
```

`pivot_table` will create two groups for you:

`screens_completed` == 0, which will pass `[2, 3]` into your aggfunc for column `sessions`.
`screens_completed` == 1, which will pass `[4, 1, 3]` into your `aggfunc` for column `sessions`

If you pass `len` to the `aggfunc` parameter, you're just asking for the length of the list passed into your `aggfunc`, which is another way of asking for how many times each `screens_completed` value occurs in your original DataFrame.

#### You can also calculate the mean by passing a mean calculating function into the `aggfunc` parameter

for example:

```
from numpy import mean
sessions_summed["mean"] = df.pivot_table(index="screens_completed", values="sessions", aggfunc=mean)
```